# Networkx / Python : Is using a class for a node better practice than defining multiple attributes?

Tags: python, graph

I've read through the NetworkX tutorial and documentation, but was unable to find real world answers for this question.

Usually when using NetworkX, I might use strings to define nodes, then set several attributes.

e.g.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('John Doe', haircolor = 'brown')
G.node['John Doe'][age] = 22
```

However, it seems like declaring a class with members instead of attributes is better in practice, especially when there are many attributes and readability might be an issue.

```
class Person:
     name = None
     age = None

Person p
p.name = 'John Doe'
p.age = 22
G.add_node(p)
```

Could someone be kind enough to validate my reasoning?  I lack the foresight to see if Networkx node/edge attributes would be preferable.

Comment: This may sound like a strange question, but are you coming from a Java background?  If so, you may be fighting the urge to 'class everything', whereas python is taking you down another route.  The first example works because python deals with *lists* efficiently, and the use of dictionaries (think: a fancy list made to look like a key-store) is common.  Notice that it took fewer lines of code in the first example - this is a good sign you are "being pythonic".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question.  However.  It seems necessary.

```
class Person:
     name = None
     age = None
```

Doesn't do what you're suggesting.

Those are two class-level attributes.  They're emphatically **not** instance variables.

Also.  You don't "declare" attributes at all.  You don't declare them like that.

`Person p` isn't proper Python.

```
p= Person()
p.name = 'John Doe'
p.age = 22
```

This emphatically does not set the class level attributes created as part of the class.  It creates additional instance-level attributes.

This may answer your question.

Networkx allows you to have any object associated with a node.

Feel free to do this

```
class Person( object ):
    def __init__( self, name, age ):
        self.name= name
        self.age= age

G.add_node('John Doe', data = Person( name='John Doe', age=22 ) )
```

Now you have all of your node data in a single object associated with the 'data' attribute.

For trivial name-value kinds of things, this is not obviously creating any real value.

But, if you have some node-specific method (rare in graph problems, but possible) then you'd have method functions associated with a node.

In graph theory problems, many of the algorithms work on the graph -- as a whole -- and you'll rarely find a use for a class with method functions.

Since the change is a trivial piece of syntax, it's probably simpler to start with

```
    G.add_node('John Doe', age=22 )
```

And migrate to

```
    G.add_node('John Doe', data = Person( name='John Doe', age=22 ) )
```

when you absolutely need to.

Comment: So if you did something like `G.add_node(p); G.add_node(p); G.add_node(p)` what about object `p` does networkx rely upon to make the last two calls effectively noops? Is it leaning on the `__hash__` for p?

Comment: Just came across this reference
*In addition to strings and integers any hashable Python object (except None) can represent a node, e.g. a customized node object, or even another Graph.* https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/ead0e65bda59862e329f2e6f1da47919c6b07ca9/networkx/classes/digraph.py#L75-L77